# Upload to AWS S3 got 403 Forbidden - Solved by remove "ACL" in param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I was developing the frontend using **React.js**, and I use **Javascript SDK** for uploading a file to my S3 bucket using my root AWS account.
I followed the official doc but kept getting 403 Forbidden. If you encounter the same case, you can try to remove the **"ACL"** in params while uploading to solve it.

I basically followed the demo code here in the official doc in the `addPhoto()` function:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album-full.html
I also referred to another blog post here:
https://medium.com/@fabianopb/upload-files-with-node-and-react-to-aws-s3-in-3-steps-fdaa8581f2bd

They all add `ACL: 'public-read'` the params in s3.upload(params) function.

```
  // Use S3 ManagedUpload class as it supports multipart uploads
  var upload = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload({
    params: {
      Bucket: albumBucketName,
      Key: photoKey,
      Body: file,
      ACL: "public-read"
    }
  });
```

But in my case, I kept getting 403 Forbidden until I simply removed this ACL field. Could someone tell me what's the reason? Or AWS updated their way to handle the ACL parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bucket probably has [Amazon S3 block public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-block-public-access.html) activated (which is default).

One of the settings is: *"Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs)"*

This means that it will block any command (such as yours) that is granting **public access** via an ACL. Your code is setting the ACL to `public-read`, which is therefore being blocked.

The intention of S3 Block Public Access is to default to a setting where nothing S3 content will not be accidentally made public. You can deactivate S3 Block Public Access to change this setting.

S3 Block Public Access is *relatively* new (November 2018), so a lot of articles on the web might have been written before the "block by default" rule came into effect.